# What are these connectors? 5 male pins with a little notch at the bottom, cables leading from a Panasonic AG-A96

Tags: identification

I've been trying to figure out the pinout of these cables, but I can't seem to find anything on them other than that they would have initially connected to a Panasonic AG-1980 VCR, and that 5V DC is supplied through one of them to the AG-A96. Any possibilities as to what the pinout is?

Edit 1: The connector is about 8-9mm in diameter, the pins closest to the notch are about 4mm from each other horizontally and 2mm vertically, and the top pin is also about 2mm from either of the closest pins.

[image: View of two cables, one labelled "RECORDER" and the other labelled "PLAYER"]
[image: A view of the interior of the connector]

Comment: I will add that it can't be S-Video, which is 4-pin and has a tab more central to the connector. It looks like some type of 5-pin mini DIN. You should provide measurements (diameter, pin spacing, etc.) to assist in finding the right kind.